# Bash script to echo line only when a parameter exceeds certain value

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Have the following lines in logs

```
queryparam={createdTime=1524456000000,limit=1000, sort=name}
queryparam={createdTime=1524457000000, sort=name,limit=1001}
queryparam={createdTime=1524457000000, sort=name, name=alpha, limit=1001}
queryparam={createdTime=1524458000000, sort=name}
```

Is there a bash script to fetch only rows which have limit greater than 1000?

P.S. Not sure how to parse the field to get limit value and check whether it is greater than 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP mentioned field is NOT always same so adding this solution now.

```
awk 'match($0,/limit=[0-9]+/){split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),array,"=");if(array[2]>1000){print}}' Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk -F"[=,]" '/limit/ && $5>1000'  Input_file
```

It will only look for those lines which have string `limit` and their value is greater than `1000` too and print them then.

***Explanation:***

```
awk -F"[=,]" '     ##Setting field separator as = and , here for all the lines of Input_file.
/limit/ && $5>1000 ##Checking here if a line contains string line in it and checking if its 5th column is grater than 1000, since awk works on concept of condition then action so here mentioning the condition and NOT mentioning the action. So by default print action of current line will happen.
' Input_file       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13. Sorry! forgot to mention. Limit value is not always the 5th parameter i.e. it is not position based.

Comment: @Silent_Pal, sure saw that, see my EDIT now and let me know if that helps?

Comment: Works. Awesome. Thank you @RavinderSingh13